# Extjs store.on('save', afterSave(resp));

Tags: ajax, json, extjs

I have a simple ExtJs (3.4) Grid with a Writer.  When the user makes some changes the store is saved to the server as follows:

```
store.on('save', afterSave(resp));
```

All is fine.  However, I want to get a response as to wheather the record has been saved successfully, failed or an update conflict happed.  How to best do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used exception listener to parse the data as suggested [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-104068.html).  But, is this the right way to do this.

```
Ext.data.DataProxy.addListener('exception', function(proxy, type, action,
options, res) {
if (type == 'response') {
var success = Ext.util.JSON.decode(res.responseText).success;
if (success) {
console.log('UPDATE OK');
} else {
console.log('UPDATE FAILED');
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ext.data.proxy.Ajax to load your stores?  If so, you can use the reader property to evaluate and handle the server responses.

Another option would be to make AJAX called directly and handle the responses from there as well

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I am using new Ext.data.HttpProxy.  I've used direct Ajax calls in the past.  But, in that case I have to loop and encode all the data from the Grids manually.