# Extjs 3.4 automatic reload grid after save new records in database

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

Using Extjs 3.4 I call the `save()` method in the `store` to save new records. The `save()` method works fine: I see the new record in the database. The problem is the `save()` method doesn't automatically reload the grid after save.

```
gridStore.save(); //Ok it works but grid is not reloaded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the server insert the data in DB he must return the new records just creates. The response must be entire new records not just the new ids. With this solution extjs parse the server response and automatically  reload the grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridStore.save();
gridStore.load();
```

**But good practice**

```
gridStore.sync({
   success: function() { 
      gridStore.load();
   }
});
```

Comment: in Extjs 3.4 there isn't sync() method

Comment: yep, therefore i wrote save() and load() at first. In the following versions of extjs preferable to use second way for save and reloading store.

Comment: Save is asyncronous, so when I call load maybe save has not finished

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527330/extjs-store-onsave-aftersaveresp

Comment: Look to my solution, i have just write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just override the autoSync property of the store to 'true' to get working done!!